# Edit to title of Suggested Edit silently discarded?

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

Have a look here:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10821405/revisions

No problem, except the top edit revision I had to do *twice*.  The first time, I hit the "Improve" button and fixed the title, but it didn't take.

Note that my change was essentially to revert the title back to the original.